# How to show and hide a view in iOS using Metal API?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, metal, metalkit

I'm using Metal to develop an app on iPad which is simple. below is a short footage of my app *-it's about psychophysics tests-* which does not use Metal API and its main problem is it has frame-drop.
[link to the gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4YDq.gif)
As I'm new to swift and the Apple environment I tried to follow tutorials whether from the Apple website or other youtube videos. but eventually, I didn't find out how to show and hide a view after a specific amount of frames.

I also tried to reuse some open-source code like [StimuliApp](https://github.com/marinraf/StimuliApp) or [PsyPad](https://github.com/davidlawson/PsyPad) or [Metal-Game-Engine-Tutorial](https://github.com/twohyjr/Metal-Game-Engine-Tutorial) but they all just make me feel more complicated.

Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason to use Metal - it seems a very low-level choice to use when it looks like you could use e.g. SpriteKit for this?

Comment: With Metal, typically you use a single "view" and render what you want, when you want it. Based on your post, I really don't think Metal is what you want to use. Looks like you can use CoreAnimation or standard UIViews plus CGGraphics. See "Creating custom shapes with CoreAnimation": https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/ios/creating-custom-shapes-with-coreanimation-coregraphics/7646